# Establishing a Secure Channel to a TEE Container in Confidential VMs on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpm, confidential-vm-tag

I am utilizing Google Cloud Platform's (GCP) Confidential Computing features, and I find it straightforward to generate and verify attestation reports using Confidential VMs. However, I am encountering a roadblock when attempting to securely integrate this into my application.

In my use case, the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) enclave within the Confidential VM is serving as a server, and there is a client outside GCP that needs to verify the TEE enclave's attestation. Afterward, the client must establish a secure communication channel with the TEE.

With Confidential VMs, the attestation part is not an issue. Post attestation, the client is aware that there is a GCP VM with a specific instance ID, and Google vouches for it running a Confidential VM image. Additionally, there is a container running on this VM with a specified SHA.

My primary concern is establishing a secure channel from the client to the VM instance. My initial approach involved using the ek_pub from the attestation report to encrypt a symmetric key, which would then be sent to the TEE. Within the TEE, I planned on utilizing the TPM for decryption. However, I discovered that access to the TPM device is not available inside the TEE container.

So, my questions are:

Is it possible to access and utilize the TPM within a TEE container in GCP's Confidential Computing environment?
Are there alternative, possibly more efficient, methods for establishing a secure communication channel between an external client and a TEE container in Confidential VMs?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.